# How to redirect traffic using only AWS services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have a static website hosted in a AWS s3 bucket "domain1.com", a cloudfront distribution in front of it redirecting all http traffic to https and a Route53 record for routing traffic to the cloudfront distribution. This is currently working but I can't seem to get the following to work:

Redirect all of the following to https://domain1.com

```
http://www.domain1.com
https://www.domain1.com
http://domain2.com
https://domain2.com
http://www.domain2.com
https://www.domain2.com
```

Does anyone has any pointers? I tried redirecting with s3+route53 but it only worked with http://domain2.com while https://domain2.com was not redirected...

Comment: Using custom domain names with HTTPS on CloudFront isn't simple. See: [Amazon CloudFront Custom SSL](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/custom-ssl-domains/) Also, what do you mean by "redirect" -- are you okay with just showing the content, or do you want the web browser to show the other domain name in the Address Bar?

Comment: ideally the domain name in the address bar should display https://domain1.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty way is to use S3 and Route 53.
Lets call the bucket "bucket-domain1-com"

```
http://www.domain1.com -> point to actual site (use mod_rewrite to change to https)
https://www.domain1.com -> point to actual site
http://domain2.com -> point to cloudfront distro -> s3 "bucket-domain1-com"
https://domain2.com -> point to cloudfront distro -> s3 "bucket-domain1-com"
http://www.domain2.com -> point to cloudfront distro -> s3 "bucket-domain1-com"
https://www.domain2.com -> point to cloudfront distro -> s3 "bucket-domain1-com"
```

Problem with S3 is that you cannot use https.
CloudFront solves this.

Then follow the instructions here to configure s3 to redirect to https://domain1.com

This is the basic idea.

Comment: Yea I realised i used the wrong URL for s3 website in cloudfront origin that's why it didn't work before . All good now thank you !